# Chamar função javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tabela-html

Eu tenho uma aplicação em VB que constrói páginas em HTML alimentadas por dados do banco. Assim, consigo emitir relatórios inserindo os dados dentro de uma tabela HTML.

Acontece, que as vezes a tabela se torna muito grande para ser impressa e preciso remover algumas colunas para que a estrutura da tabela caiba certinho no papel. Precisaria então ocultar ou remover colunas, quando a tabela ultrapassasse certa largura. Mas esta ação deveria ocorrer no evento onload, pois minha tabela é escrita por um programa VB e então o código em JS só entra em ação quando a página é aberta pelo usuario.

Como faria então, para remover as colunas de modo que minha tabela sempre tenha a largura de 2400px por exemplo.

?!?! poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Cara, eu não sei dar uma resposta muito direta, mas posso te indicar uma ferramenta excelente e muito ágil para você definir layouts responsivos para seus sites. Dê uma olhada no Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ . Não sei se você conhece ele é simplesmente um css, totalmente responsivo, e que tem muito layout de tabela já pronta. Tabelas interativas, e etc. Veja: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables . Talvez isso possa te adiantar pra muita coisa.

Comment: Cara, valeu pela dica, gostei muito dessa alternativa. No entanto, ela ainda nao resolve minha questao. No caso deste projeto, o layout responsivo não tem relevância alguma e sim o tamanho do componente em si. Mas de qualquer forma, sua dica foi bacana e vi muita coisa útil por la que inclusive pretendo usar. Muito grato! Por hora, só preciso saber como remover colunas de uma table, utilizando JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar CSS, para eliminar as colunas apenas na impressão:

**CSS:**

```
.no-print {
    opacity:.5;
}
@media print {
    .no-print {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Coluna 1</td>
<td>Coluna 2</td>
<td>Coluna 3</td>
<td class="no-print">Coluna 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Coluna 1</td>
<td>Coluna 2</td>
<td>Coluna 3</td>
<td class="no-print">Coluna 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Coluna 1</td>
<td>Coluna 2</td>
<td>Coluna 3</td>
<td class="no-print">Coluna 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Fiz uma adaptação em jquery para Adicionar ou Remover a classe ao clicar na coluna:.

**jquery:**

```
$('td').click(function() {
    var indice = $(this).index() + 1;
    $(this).parents('table').find('td:nth-child('+indice+')').toggleClass('no-print');
});
```

**jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/tfmpouse/1/**